# How to change specific fields in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have a table as follows:
[image]

I want to update the following data:

```
Array
(
    [Reseller] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan
            [mobile] => 01673050495
            [email] => kuet.absb@yahoo.com
        )

)
```

keeping unchanged others. So How can I do this. I try with saveField. It works for only one field updating at a time.

N.B: I am using cakephp 2.9

Comment: use  console and bake all ressellers, then see edit method and view.  When edit / update  post you must set id in form or method of that post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data['id'] = 1;
$data['name']  = 'Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan';
$data['mobile'] = '01673050495';
$data['email'] = 'kuet.absb@yahoo.com';

$this->Reseller->save($data,false);
```

Never forget to put the field `id` for which you are updating the record.